# Can't store temperature in variable ( for further processing)

Tags: arduino-uno, variables, temperature-sensor

I am trying to store temperature data in a variable, so that I can use it for making a JSON object, but the problem is, that when I try to store the temperature in a variable, it prints out the wrong value. I'm using a DHT11 temperature/humidity sensor and a library for calculating the temperature.

```
Serial.print("Temperature (°C): ");
Serial.println((float)DHT11.temperature, DEC);
int temp1 = ((float)DHT11.temperature, DEC);
Serial.println(temp1);
```

These 4 lines is printing out this:

```
Temperature (Â°C): 23.0000000000
10
```

The first one is correct, but the second line should also be saying "23".
I have tried only loading the data in once with the library, as in outcommenting one line, but that does not work.
It's like I have some syntax wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

> ```
> int temp1 = ((float)DHT11.temperature, DEC);
> ```

casts `DHT11.temperature` to an `float`, throws away the value, then assigns `DEC` to `temp1`. That is not what you want.

> ```
> int temp1 = DHT11.temperature;
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed it straight away. I knew it was just some stupid syntax that I was doing wrong, but I just couldn't figure out what. Thnx.

Comment: For extra reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator